# Close tab and end current page in browser. When I restart FireFox, Chrome or other browser on Android phone or tablet, last page browsed comes up

Tags: firefox-for-android, browser

On my Windows computer, if I close a browser page, the next time I launch the browser, it goes to my home location. This is true regardless of the browser so far as I can tell.

On my Android tablets (Samsung Galaxy 10, Amazon Fire Tablet) or phone if I close the browser and then reopen it, it returns to the last page browsed, not to a home page. I have to back out from the last page back to the original page to get to that.

How can I change this so that upon opening a fresh page, it goes to a home page?

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox on Android as of 89.1.1:

1. Go into settings
2. Scroll down to `Delete browsing data on quit` under the `Privacy and security` header.
3. Enable `Delete browsing data on quit`.
4. **Untick**(!) everything *except* `Open tabs`.

...and now it should forget the previously opened tabs, and thus instead start the home page, after you quit the browser.

Unfortunately I can't help with Chrome.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox > settings> advanced> restore tabs
[image]